# Should I add some noise when the dataset is small?

Tags: datasets

I want to create a small dataset (about 10 classes and 20-30 images each), should I add some noise (wrong label sample) in the training, validation and test datasets, and why?

Comment: Hi. Are you asking whether you should or not deliberately add some noise to the dataset? I've added the word "add" to your question, but I am unsure if this was the actual word missing.

Comment: What is your purpose in creating the dataset? What do you hope to achieve? We need to know in order to answer whether adding noise would be useful